# How do I query a database with php using bind variables?

Tags: php, sql, database, prepared-statement, where-clause

I'm making a song database system, and I'm trying to implement a way for users to search songs based on a category to search (song's name, artist's name, album name, genre etc) and a given search term. To accommodate user input and protect against SQL injection, I'm using a prepared statement made with bind variables, however I'm having trouble with what I currently made:

```
   search("genre", "electropop", $db);
   function search($column, $term, $db) {
     try {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE :column=:term;";
      $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
      $params = array("column" => $column,
                      "term" => $term);
      $stmt->execute($params);
      $arr = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      print (json_encode($arr));
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
      catch_error("The search failed.", $ex);
    }
  }
```

Whenever I test this, I get an empty array back: `[ ]`
I tested my query ("SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE genre='electropop'") in phpmyadmin and it checks out (gave me back entries).
The correct syntax for WHERE clauses in SQL is that the term needs to be surrounded by quotations (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) so I tried escaping quotation marks around the term:

```
  ...
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE :column=\':term;\'";
  ...
```

But then it fails to even see :term as a token to bind variables to later.

Not sure how to go about solving this. I assumed the empty array is due to a valid search but just no results, but perhaps I'm not correctly using a prepared statement. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `:` before `term` param. Don't need to bind column name. Just use the `$column` var instead of `:column`.

```
search("genre", "electropop", $db);
function search($column, $term, $db) {
try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE $column=:term;";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $params = array(":term" => $term);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    $arr = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print (json_encode($arr));
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        catch_error("The search failed.", $ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow ok completely missed that. Thanks for the catch :D